# Why my Angular 8 project doesn't work on GitHub pages

Tags: angular, github, deployment, github-pages, angular-router

could you help me? I'm trying to deploy an Angular 8 personal project to GitHub pages but it appears blank, and I don't know the why.

It's the first time that I try to deploy using GH-pages, I've not used the angular cli tool for deploying on gh, merely I've created a new repository and then I've added all the compiled files.

**this is my repository.**
https://github.com/Gerguevara/angularnews

**this is the gh-pages url**
https://gerguevara.github.io/angularnews/

Also I've tried to deploy it using NOW but I couldn't, I got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because you didn't set your app base href before deploy to github. Your app is looking for files in "https://gerguevara.github.io/" directory, not in your respository "https://gerguevara.github.io/angularnews" directory

In your index.html file the `<base href="/">` part suppose to be `<base href="angularnews">`. You can either change that with CLI or with your IDE

Answer (score 1):

I must say this is interesting because I was able to get it to load. [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l01fF.png)

Have you tried just dropping it into a web server and see how it operates. Understand that loading the files locally will give you issues because local file access is not allowed without permissions.

Just for a little additional help.

One thing I did notice is in your first news item I seen:

[[getSimpleString(data.title)]] [[getSimpleString(data.description)]] [[getSimpleString(data.videoCountText)]]

This issue shows you need to be a little more defensive in your programming. Make sure that only data that can be displayed properly is returned from your API or server call. Also, you could make each news item a component and hide/show the component only if sufficient data is available for display.

Happy programming ;-)